# Local maximum and global maximum of $\sin$

Tags: maxima-minima

In book it is written that $\sin(x)$ has both local maximum and global maximum at $\pi/2$ but the highest value $\sin$ can have is $1$ and that is at $\pi/2$. Should not it be only global maximum?

Comment: A point can be global maximum and local maximum at the same time. Remember in the definitions of local maximum and global maximum, it is possible for a point to be both of them.

Comment: is the global maximum not unique?

Comment: It does not have to be unique. It just has to be greater than or **equal to** all other values.

Answer (score 1):

A global maximum is always a local maximum but the inverse doesn't always happen to be true.